# Tensforflow.JS: loss value in training output in decimal notation

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

is there a way to get loss values in decimal instead of scientific notation?

While training a model, it seems that if the loss value has two (or three) ceros after the point it will convert it to cientific notation:

```
Epoch 48 / 50
eta=0.0 ===================================================================> 
2029ms 317us/step - loss=3.68e-3 val_loss=2.80e-3 
Epoch 49 / 50
eta=0.0 ===================================================================> 
2311ms 361us/step - loss=1.23e-3 val_loss=1.84e-3 
Epoch 50 / 50
eta=0.0 ===================================================================> 
1872ms 292us/step - loss=1.47e-3 val_loss=1.41e-3
```

Thanks!

Comment: What difference does it make to have it in decimal rather than scientific notation ?

Comment: It's a personal preference and I wan't to know if I that feature is tuneable or if I have to turn verbose to 0 and log my own output using event handlers (for example).

Comment: Using a callback after each epoch can help to render customize log.